# mod_rewrite rule not working without file extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im doing a really basic rule for mod_rewrite and cant make it work.
I want the url: "https://www.example.com/index.php?req=login" be "https://www.example.com/login"

The htaccess file is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?req=$1 [L]
```

I get redirected to index.php but if i print $_GET the result is this:

```
Array ( [req] => index.php )
```

When it should be "login" instead of "index.php"

If I put an extension to the wanted rule as .html and make the rule as this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?req=$1 [L]
```

it works just fine and i get the "req" key with the "login" value wanted.

Cant figure out how to make it work with no extension.

Update:
Adding some string at the beginning of the pattern also works fine:

```
RewriteRule ^request/([^/]*)$ index.php?req=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

The point is you have to exclude index.php from the rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?index\.php$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?req=$1 [L]
```

After each rewrite the hole thing will be done again. So first rewrite looks like this:
 `/login` to `/index.php?req=login` but now the server is checking if he has to do another rule for the new URL. If you exclude the `index.php` than we are fine.

Of course if you add some extra strings (e.g. `.html` or `request/`) that are not include in `index.php` than you are not making the second round, but this is only a workaround not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([a-z\-A-Z]+)
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?req=%1 [L]
```

Comment: This will also mach `/page/subpage` and rewrite it to `index.php?req=page` I'm not sure if this is intended but `/page1` will not work